# ButtonGroup: Quantity of selected elements

Tags: java, swing, selected, jtogglebutton, buttongroup

How do I get the quantity of all selected JToggleButtons in a ButtonGroup?

```
ButtonGroup bGroup = new ButtonGroup();
bGreen = new JToggleButton("Green");
bYellow = new JToggleButton("Yellow");
bRed = new JToggleButton("Red");

bGroup.add(bGreen);
bGroup.add(bYellow);
bGroup.add(bRed);
```

Comment: `quantity of all selected elements in a ButtonGroup`, which one apples or bananas, for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise this question is simple un_answerable

Comment: I guess he wants to say "how many elements from the ButtonGroup are selected?"

Comment: Yes, how many of the JToggleButtons are selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways. For example `bGroup.getSelection().getSelectedObjects().length`.
You can also call `getElements()`, then iterate over enumeration and ask `isSelected()` for each button.
Please refer to API doc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a item listener to each of the toogle

```
public int counter = 0;
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
    {
         counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        counter --;
    } 
}
```